# Pass a variable to url from a servicetask to another

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I’m trying to pass a variable from a service task to another, so I can pass it in the URL of that service task.
Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to transport data from one task to another, the safest and most flexible way is to store the data in a process variable.

So in ServiceTask-A:

```
 ...
 public void execute(DelegateExecution ex) {
      ex.setVariable("myUrl",  "https://stackoverflow.com");
 }
```

and in ServiceTask-B:

```
 ...
 public void execute(DelegateExecution ex) {
      String myUrl = (String)ex.getVariable("myUrl");
      // myUrl now contains "https://stackoverflow.com"
 }
```